# Interpret this expression $\left \| A \right \| _1 = \max \limits _{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |$

Tags: matrices, notation, normed-spaces

The "$1$" norm of a matrix (*in some cases*, which cases?), [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm), is defined as follows:

$$\left \| A \right \| _1 = \max \limits _{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |$$

Then there's an example of the matrix

$$ 
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
           -3 & 5 & 7 \\
           2 & 6 & 4 \\
           0 & 2 & 8 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$

and its "$1$" norm is calculated as follows

$$||A||_1 = max(|−3|+2+0, 5+6+2, 7+4+8) = max(5,13,19) = 19$$

which suprises me, because the way I read $\left \| A \right \| _1 = \max \limits _{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |$ is different, and is the following

> Sum the maximum elements in absolute value of each row from row $i$ to $m$

and this interpretation would lead me to the result $|7| + |6| + |8| = 21$.

What makes mathematicians think that the notation above does not mean how I interpret it? How would you interpret it personally?

Comment: "Sum the maximum elements in absolute value of each row from row ii to m" -- that would then be the expression $\sum_{i=1}^m \max_{1\leq j \leq n} |a_{ij}|$. It's the order you're doing the operations in which is leading to the confusion

Answer (score 1):

$$
\max _{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |
$$

should be read as follows:

$$
\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \left(\sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |\right)
$$.

That is, for each fixed $j$, you first evaluate $\sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |$. For a fixed $j$, $\sum _{i=1} ^m | a_{ij} |$ is the sum of the absolute value of the elements in the $j$th column. Once you have computed all of these sums, you take the maximum one.

Essentially, your confusion comes because you misinterpreted the order of the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation given is correct. The max is taken on the sum and not the other way around. Your interpretation would be written as:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} | a_{ij} |
$$

Hope that helps!